# Cursor get column index for radio group

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, android-studio

I'm basically looking for a solution to re-select a radio button within a radio group on a form, by using a cursor that looks through a database. I used it to load a user profile and I want to load whether the user is male or female.

Here is the code for the other elements I'm loading:

```
    DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor cr = dbh.ObtainSignUpActivityDetails();

    cr.moveToFirst();
    TextView DOBView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editDOB);
    DOBView.setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DOB")));
    TextView HeightView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editHeight);
    HeightView.setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Height")));
    TextView WeightView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editWeight);
    WeightView.setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Weight")));
```

My genders are stored in the database as 0 = male, 1 = female:

```
    if(GenderMaleRadio.isChecked())
    {
        gender = false;
    }
    else if(GenderFemaleRadio.isChecked())
    {
        gender = true;
    }
```

My attempt at the code was (I know it's wrong but I am a complete beginner and have no idea what I'm doing):

```
    RadioGroup GenderView = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    GenderView.check(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("Gender")))
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I have a radio group with 2 radio buttons: male and female. 
I would like to figure out the code to select whether the record in the database shows whether the user is a male (0) or a female (1) and then re-select the correct radio button in the radio group when the form loads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this 
`((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("Gender")))).setChecked(true);`

and put in the `Radiogroup` the first `Radiobutton` is the male and second is the female